# GKE cluster creator in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

How can we get the cluster owner details in GKE. Logging part only contains the entry with service account operations and there is no entry with principal email of userId anywhere.

It seems very difficult to get the name of the user who created the GKE cluster.

we have exported complete json file of logs but did not the user entry who actually click on create cluster button. I think this is very common use case to know GKE cluster creator, not sure if we are missing something.

Query:

```
resource.type="k8s_cluster"
resource.labels.cluster_name="clusterName"
resource.labels.location="us-central1"
-protoPayload.methodName="io.k8s.core.v1.configmaps.update"
-protoPayload.methodName="io.k8s.coordination.v1.leases.update"
-protoPayload.methodName="io.k8s.core.v1.endpoints.update"
severity=DEFAULT
-protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail="system:addon-manager"
-protoPayload.methodName="io.k8s.apiserver.flowcontrol.v1beta1.flowschemas.status.patch"
-protoPayload.methodName="io.k8s.certificates.v1.certificatesigningrequests.create"
-protoPayload.methodName="io.k8s.core.v1.resourcequotas.delete"
-protoPayload.methodName="io.k8s.core.v1.pods.create"
-protoPayload.methodName="io.k8s.apiregistration.v1.apiservices.create"
```

I have referred the link below, but it did not help either.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/finding-your-gke-logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit) and specifically [Admin Activity Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#admin-activity)

And, there's a "trick": The activity audit log entries include the API method. You can find the API method that interests you. This isn't super straightforward but it's relatively easy. You can start by scoping to the service. For GKE, the service is `container.googleapis.com`.

> **NOTE** [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) and [Kubenetes Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/) (but really `container.googleapis.com`) and [`projects.locations.clusters.create`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.clusters/create). The mechanism breaks down a little here as the `protoPayload.methodName` is a variant of the underlying REST method name.

And so you can use logs explorer with the following very broad query:

```
logName="projects/{PROJECT}/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
container.googleapis.com
```

> **NOTE** replace `{PROJECT}` with the value.

And then refine this based on what's returned:

```
logName="projects/{PROJECT}/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
protoPayload.serviceName="container.googleapis.com"
protoPayload.methodName="google.container.v1beta1.ClusterManager.CreateCluster"
```

> **NOTE** I mentioned that it isn't super straightforward because, as you can see in the above, I'd used `gcloud beta container clusters create` and so I need the `google.container.v1beta1.ClusterManager.CreateCluster` method but, it was easy to determine this from the logs.

And, who dunnit?

```
protoPayload: {
  authenticationInfo: {
    principalEmail: "{me}"
  }
}
```

So:

```bash
PROJECT="[YOUR-PROJECT]"

FILTER="
logName=\"projects/${PROJECT}/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity\"
protoPayload.serviceName=\"container.googleapis.com\"
protoPayload.methodName=\"google.container.v1beta1.ClusterManager.CreateCluster\"
"

gcloud logging  read "${FILTER}" \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. It helped us to get the cluster owner.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm pleased to hear it helped.

Comment: and also Thanks for explaining the api method part in logging..:). It helps.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for a quick answer.

Use the log filter in Logs Explorer & use below to check the creator of the cluster.

```
resource.type="gke_cluster"
protoPayload.authorizationInfo.permission="container.clusters.create"
resource.labels.cluster_name="your-cluster-name"
```

From gcloud command, you can get the creation date of the cluster.

```
gcloud container clusters describe YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME --zone ZONE
```