# I am doing an audit of all GCP services. Is there a way to find out what user created the services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a very simple bash script that I run that creates a list of services I have in the cloud:

```
#!/bin/bash
##############################################################
#  This script will list all services in all projects in GCP #
##############################################################

for PROJECT in $(\
  gcloud projects list \
  --format="value(projectId)")
do
  echo "Project: ${PROJECT}"
  echo "-----------  Services  -----------"
  gcloud services list --project=${PROJECT}
  echo "-----------  Kubernetes Clusters  -----------"
  gcloud container clusters list --project=${PROJECT} | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v NAME
  echo "-----------  Compute Engine instances  -----------"
  gcloud compute instances list --project=${PROJECT} | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v NAME
  echo "-----------  SQL Instance List -----------"
  gcloud sql instances list --project=${PROJECT} | grep -v NAME | awk '{print $1}'
  echo "-----------  BigTable Instance List ----------"
  gcloud bigtable instances list --project=${PROJECT}
  echo "-----------  PubSub Topic List  ----------"
  gcloud pubsub topics list --project=${PROJECT} | sed 's/---//g' | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' | awk '{print $2}'
  echo "-----------  Functions List ----------"
  gcloud functions list --project=${PROJECT} | grep -v NAME | awk '{print $1}'
  echo "-----------  Datflow jobs List  ----------"
  gcloud dataflow jobs list --project=${PROJECT} | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v NAME
  echo "-----------  Redis Instance List ----------"

  for REGION in `gcloud compute regions list | grep -v NAME | awk '{print $1}'`
    do
     gcloud redis instances list --region=$REGION | grep -v NAME | awk '{print $1}'
  done

  #echo "-----------  Service Accounts  ------------"
  #for ACCOUNT in $(\
    #gcloud iam service-accounts list \
    #--project=${PROJECT} \
    #--format="value(email)")
  #do
    #echo "---------- Service Account keys: ${ACCOUNT}  -----------"
    #gcloud iam service-accounts list --project=${PROJECT} | grep -v NAME | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq
  #done
```

Is there a way I can figure out what user created these services?   I now have a bunch of rouge services that I do not know who they belong to.    Is there a way I can add a feature to my script to get the original user that created the service?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72451093/609290).

The approach is to grep the Cloud Audit logs for the `google.api.serviceusage.v1.ServiceUsage.EnableService` method and then the enabler is `protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail` and (less confidently) the service that was enabled appears (!?) to be in any of the slice elements under `protoPayload.authorizationInfo` (example below uses one).

```bash
PROJECT=...
FILTER="
logName=\"projects/${PROJECT}/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity\" 
protoPayload.methodName=\"google.api.serviceusage.v1.ServiceUsage.EnableService\"
"

WHOM="protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail"
WHAT="protoPayload.authorizationInfo[0].resource"

gcloud logging read "${FILTER}" \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(${WHOM},${WHAT})"
```

Comment: Thanks @dazwilkin.  I tried your script.  I set the project to my project but when I run your script it does not output anything.    I am thinking the WHOM/WHAT need to be something valid on my end?

Comment: It assumes the environment variable `PROJECT` which should be set by your existing script. The `FILTER` should be expanded with the value of the `PROJECT` variable too. You can expand the whole script into a single line to test it. Try dropping the `--format` flag entirely to ensure it's working.

Comment: `gcloud logging read 'logName="projects/[[PROJECT]]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity protoPayload.methodName="google.api.serviceusage.v1.ServiceUsage.EnableService"'` should work. Replace `[[PROJECT]]` with the value of your Project ID.

Comment: Well I have tried to the best of my ability.  The good news is I do not get an error when I run the gcloud logging.    But I just get nothing lol.

Comment: OK. Let's take this step-by-step. Does `gcloud logging read --project=${PROJECT} --limit=5` work? If so, what about adding in the basic filter `gcloud logging read "logName=\"projects/${PROJECT}/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity\"" --project=${PROJECT} --limit=5`?

Comment: I was able to get it to work I had to change my script a bit


`FILTER="
`logName=\"projects/${PROJECT}/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity\"
`protoPayload.serviceName=\"pubsub.googleapis.com\"
`protoPayload.methodName=\"google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.CreateTopic\"
`protoPayload.request.name=\"${request}\""

`gcloud logging  read "${FILTER}" --`format="value(protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail)" \
`--project=${PROJECT}
Unfortunately the email it is extracts seems to be a "catchall" email address that is assigned to my companies GCP account.