# How to find the service account used for creating a resource in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, service-accounts

I am new to GCP. I created a GKE cluster using a service account that I have forgotten now. I see a list of service account information in Service accounts page but I forgot which one I used.

Is there any ways to find the name of the service account that I used from GKE cluster information?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72451093/609290).

Answer (score 3):

You can try going to the Kubernetes Engine > Cluster > Nodes

Under "Nodes Pools" click the "Name" scroll down to "Instance Groups" then scroll down to "Instance Group Members" and click one of the vm instance and then scroll down to "API and identity management" to see the service account used.